# Compilation error/issues while executing maven install

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project and try to do a maven install.While performing the maven install, Im getting the below error.

```
[INFO] Compiling 403 source files to D:\\iTT_Backend\itt\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/iTT_Backend/itt/src/main/java/com/iowe/bean/Project.java:[5,27] 
package com.cx.util does not exist
[ERROR] 
/D:/iTT_Backend/itt/src/main/java/com/itt/controller/ScanController.java: 
[21,39] package com.cx.business.to.scan does not exist
```

Above is the error Im getting while trying to do a clean install.The specified package in the above error message package com.cx.util is available as part of the itt.jar. That jar has been added as a dependency to this project. I dont see any errors in eclipse. Only while trying to do install, Im getting the above compilation error.

**Analysis Done**
Below are the analysis done

- Checked for the dependency and the jar is available as part of dependency in pom.xml file.
- The application does not show any dependency error in eclipse. Its able to navigate to the corresponding method in the jar file.The issue occurs while executing mvn install command.
- Tried executing mvn install via command prompt. Still getting the same error as above.
- Have renamed the .m2 repository folder to old repository and re executed the mvn install command. same issue exists.

Need help in getting the above issue resolved. 
Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove from .m2 local repository and execute command mvn clean install
2. Try to remove and add again dependency in Pom.xml

Comment: Mykhailo Moskura Thanks for the quick esponse. I have done that too. I have renamed the m2 repository folder to old repository and re executed the command. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure jar is installed with the package in it ?

Comment: My question is jar cached again in .m2 repo while you removed and executed command again ?

Comment: Is this dependency from remote repo of from m2 central?

Comment: I have checked the jar(unzipped the jar and checked the contents) that has been generated after the execution of the install command and could see that the package in question is available as part of the jar. The dependency is created from an other local maven project.

Comment: Is it multimodule maven project or not?

Comment: Its not a multimodule maven project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184847/discussion-between-mykhailo-moskura-and-vr3w3c9).